# Escanear todo el dom de una pagina cualquiera

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito escanear todo el DOM de cualquier pagina, es posible?

estoy intentando pero no logro obtener absolutamente todo, solo obtengo una parte

```js
function findhead1() {
  var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

  for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
    console.log(all[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="findhead1()">
  <div class="postcell post-layout--right">

    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">

      <p>I labeled some pixels of a picture as foreground and the rest of them are unlabeled yet. I want to use SVM and the labeled pixels's properties like color as SVM input to label the remaining pixels as background or foreground. Is that possible with
        one-class as input? Or do I need some pixels labeled as background (two-class input)?
        <br>Thanks in advance.<br> Edit: I found <br>
        <a href="http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html" rel="nofollow">http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html</a> <br> and <br>
        <a href="http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/" rel="nofollow">http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/</a> <br> For one-class SVM, but I dont know how to use it in matlab.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="post-taglist grid gs4 gsy fd-column">
      <div class="grid ps-relative d-block">
        <a href="/questions/tagged/matlab" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'matlab'" rel="tag">matlab</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/svm" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'svm'" rel="tag">svm</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb0 ">
      <div class="mt16 pt4 grid gs8 gsy fw-wrap jc-end ai-start">
        <div class="grid--cell mr16" style="flex: 1 1 100px;">
          <div class="post-menu"><a href="/q/34400186/5590777" title="short permalink to this question" class="short-link" itemprop="url" id="link-post-34400186">share</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/34400186/edit" class="suggest-edit-post" title="revise and improve this post">edit</a>
            <span class="lsep">|</span><a href="#" class="flag-post-link" title="flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention" data-postid="34400186">flag</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="post-signature grid--cell">
          <div class="user-info ">
            <div class="user-action-time">
              <a href="/posts/34400186/revisions" title="show all edits to this post">edited <span title="2015-12-22 14:04:27Z" class="relativetime">Dec 22 '15 at 14:04</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="user-gravatar32">
              <a href="/users/5575911/hatze">
                <div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mykSw.png?s=32&amp;g=1" alt="" width="32" height="32"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="user-details">
              <a href="/users/5575911/hatze">hatze</a>
              <div class="-flair">
                <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">469</span><span title="5 silver badges"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">5</span></span><span title="11 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span>
                <span class="badgecount">11</span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-signature owner grid--cell">
          <div class="user-info ">
            <div class="user-action-time">
              asked <span title="2015-12-21 16:25:47Z" class="relativetime">Dec 21 '15 at 16:25</span>
            </div>
            <div class="user-gravatar32">
              <a href="/users/3365425/majid-r">
                <div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1611068897b3bef445030a8176be0637?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" alt="" width="32" height="32"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="user-details" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
              <a href="/users/3365425/majid-r">Majid.r</a><span class="d-none" itemprop="name">Majid.r</span>
              <div class="-flair">
                <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">82</span><span title="1 silver badge"><span class="badge2"></span><span class="badgecount">1</span></span><span title="9 bronze badges"><span class="badge3"></span>
                <span class="badgecount">9</span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con:

```
document.querySelectorAll("*");
```

Comment: en la consola no veo la clase "postcell" por lo tanto no obtengo ese elemento

Comment: @x-rw no lo ves porque la consola está limitada a X mensajes. Si en lugar de poner `all.length` pones `15`, sí que se ve.

Comment: @Bryro, aunque esto responde a la respuesta, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de información: ¿qué es `querySelectorAll`? ¿dónde iría en el código de arriba? Lee [answer] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.